# AJAX post in external JS file with Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I'm trying to make an AJAX post request from one of my Django webpages but it isn't working. I suspect that the issue is due to me not knowing how to correctly reference the URL in the external javascript file (which is located in a sub-folder of the static folder). The window alert halfway down my Javascript file is displaying correctly so I know the code is executing down to there, but the POST isn't happening.

Many thanks in advance for any pointers on how to fix this.

Views.py:

```
@csrf_exempt
def survey(request):
   survey_response = Post.objects.all()
   post = Post.objects.get(question=u'Are you happy with your waste management services?')

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['start[action]']=="geolocation":
      latitude = request.POST['start[latitude]']
      longitude = request.POST['start[longitude]']

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['start[action]']=="ethereum":
      transaction_id = request.POST['start[transaction_id]']
      print transaction_id

    return render(request, 'poll/survey.html', {'survey_response': survey_response})
```

Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^survey/', views.survey, name='survey'),]
```

Javascript excerpt (located at static/poll/javascript/votes.js)

```
function yesVote(){
var transaction_ID= sendM.increaseYes.sendTransaction({from:council});
sendTransaction(transaction_ID);
}

function noVote(){
var transaction_ID=sendM.increaseNo.sendTransaction({from:council});
sendTransaction(transaction_ID);
}

function sendTransaction(transaction_ID){
var ethereum = "ethereum";
window.alert("HI");
$.ajax({
url: "/survey/",
type:"POST",
data: {start:{
  action:ethereum,
    transaction:transaction_ID}
  },
dataType:'json',
success: function(data){
alert('success'+data);
}
})}
```

Comment: Can you print `request.POST` and share it here?

Comment: Just a small thing: it should be `datatype` not `dataType`.

Comment: Found the error - it should have been "transaction_id = request.POST['start[transaction_id]']". Also had to correct the datatype spelling mistake. Thanks both

Answer (score 0):

There was a mistake in views.py, incorrectly referencing the data from the AJAX post as ['start[transaction_id]'] instead of ['start[transaction]']

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST['start[action]']=="ethereum":
  transaction_id = request.POST['start[transaction]']
```